# Add android:name to application tag of AndroidManifest.xml using Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is this possible? I'd like to do this automatically, not by letting the user do it manually. 
I'm talking about the existing application tag. I need this because I need to initialize something before the activity starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No command is available from cordova-cli docs:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/README.md

Change is not only as easy as to change in config xml. Directory structure on platform projects are different depending on namespaces. This could be the main difficulty to apply changes.